# Entity framework generating wrong SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity

I am attempting to insert a record through Entity Framework and it appears the SQL generated is incorrect. I am inserting into the 'PostingSelections' table. This table has FK's to three other tables 'PropertyPosting', 'PropertySummary' and 'User'. The FK to User is nullable. This is using a MySQL database, which I am suspicious is the problem.

The DDL for the PostingSelections table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `PostingSelections`(
    `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE, 
    `SelectionType` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    `Date` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `SourceIPAddress` longtext NOT NULL, 
    `PropertyPosting_Id` int NOT NULL, 
    `PropertySummary_Id` int NOT NULL, 
    `User_Id` int);
```

My code is:

```
var postingselection = new postingselection();
postingselection.PropertyPosting_Id = 24;
postingselection.PropertySummary_Id = 24;  
postingselection.SelectionType = 1;  
postingselection.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;  
postingselection.SourceIPAddress = "TBD";   

db.postingselections.Add(postingselection);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The code is exactly the same as what is automatically generated by entityframework when I generate the controller automatically. The SQL that EF is generating is:

```
INSERT INTO `postingselections`(
`SelectionType`, 
`Date`, 
`SourceIPAddress`, 
`PropertyPosting_Id`, 
`PropertySummary_Id`, 
`User_Id`, 
`propertyposting_Id`, 
`propertysummary_Id`, 
`user_Id`) VALUES (
1, 
4/18/2017, 
TBD, 
24, 
24, 
0, 
24, 
24, 
NULL);
SELECT
`Id`
FROM `postingselections`
 WHERE  row_count() > 0 AND `Id`=last_insert_id()
```

See how it has generated three columns twice? PropertyPosting_Id, PropertyPosting_Id and User_Id? The error that is generated as expected is:

> Failed in 71 ms with error: Column 'User_Id' specified twice

Could someone please help? This is a very basic insert, and I can't find any other similar postings. I can only conclude I have found a bug in EF for mySQL and will have to do this instead with a manual SQL statement.

Comment: What does your entity object look like?

Comment: May be user id is not nullable in object. If that's the case it should be something like int? userId { get; set; }

Comment: Since all 3 dupe fields are foreign-key (FK) related, seems that one-to-many relationship between them with non-nullable column triggers the issue. Try using nullable value types for all FKs.

Comment: Post your full entity model. And show navigation properties as well

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem few days ago, I think it's related to the the Primary Key of "PostingSelections" table.

Try to specify a PK for your table, otherwise EF wont differentiate the records.